# Solving run-time error in Thiessen polygons command line

Tags: arcobjects, vba, vb.net, vbscript

I call Procedure 2 from a loop that is within Procedure 1 (see below). The program stacks in the line that creates Thiessen polygons i.e. GP.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis....
That line is highlighted yellow and arises the message “a run-time error -2147467259 (80004005)”. Below I note Procedures 1 and 2 in VBA. The strange thing is that when I run Procedure 2 isolated by typing the arguments works fine.

```
'PROCEDURE 1
Public Sub CreateNewGeneration(BlockID As String)
CreateMatingTable

Dim NumLayers As Integer
Dim index As Integer

NumLayers = CountLayersMP(BlockID)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j = NumLayers


Dim Mp1 As Integer
Dim MP2 As Integer
Dim Sol1 As Integer
Dim Sol2 As Integer
Mp1 = 0
MP2 = 0
Sol1 = 0
Sol2 = 0

Dim UpperBound As Integer
Dim LowerBound As Integer

UpperBound = NumLayers
LowerBound = 1

'Select randomly two numbers from 1 to NumLayers

 Dim check2 As Boolean
check2 = False

For i = 1 To j


 ReRandom:
 Mp1 = Int((UpperBound - LowerBound + 1) * Rnd + LowerBound)
 MP2 = Int((UpperBound - LowerBound + 1) * Rnd + LowerBound)

  If Mp1 = MP2 Then
   GoTo ReRandom

  End If

Sol1 = GetSol(Mp1)
Sol2 = GetSol(MP2)


If Sol1 = Sol2 Then
GoTo ReRandom
End If

Dim strSol1 As String
Dim strSol2 As String
Dim strMP1 As String
Dim strMP2 As String
Dim stri As String
strSol1 = CStr(Sol1)
strSol2 = CStr(Sol2)
strMP1 = CStr(Mp1)
strMP2 = CStr(MP2)



If i = 1 Then

Call MoveCentroidsonAverage(BlockID, strSol1, strSol2, strMP1, strMP2)
Call CreateCrossOverSolution(BlockID, strSol1, strSol2, strMP1, strMP2, i)
Call UpdateMatingTable(Mp1, MP2, Sol1, Sol2)
End If

If i > 1 Then
check2 = CheckMatingTable(Mp1, MP2, Sol1, Sol2)
    If check2 = True Then
GoTo ReRandom

Else

Call MoveCentroidsonAverage(BlockID, strSol1, strSol2, strMP1, strMP2)

'CALL PROCEDURE 2 (CreateCrossOverSolution) which is shown after the End Sub

Call CreateCrossOverSolution(BlockID, strSol1, strSol2, strMP1, strMP2, i)
Call UpdateMatingTable(Mp1, MP2, Sol1, Sol2)
   End If
End If
'
Sol1 = 0
Sol2 = 0

 Next i


Call DeleteMPtables("1")
Call DeleteMPtables("2")
Call DeleteLayersMP("VectorB", BlockID)
Call DeleteMatingTable

End Sub


'PROCEDURE 2
Public Sub CreateCrossOverSolution(BlockID As String, Solindex1 As String, Solindex2   As String, _
MPindex1 As String, MPindex2 As String, popNo As Integer)

Dim GP As Object

Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")

'''''' Set the necessary product code
GP.SetProduct "ArcInfo"
'Set the toolbox
 GP.AddToolbox "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Conversion Tools.tbx"
 GP.AddToolbox "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Analysis Tools.tbx"
 GP.AddToolbox "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx"



GP.Extent = "144566.589424817 351191.130242809 145772.160174817 353810.742942809"

Dim Output_Feature_Class As String
Dim Thiessens As String
Dim LandBlock As String
Dim strPopNo As String
strPopNo = CStr(popNo)

'**************The line that causes the run-time error 
GP.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis "C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\CentroidsB" & BlockID  & ".shp", _
"C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\ThiessenNew" & BlockID & "_" & popNo & ".shp", "ONLY_FID"


UpdateCentroidsB (BlockID)


'''' 'Select block
GP.Select_analysis "C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\LandBlocks.shp", _
"C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\LandBlock" & BlockID & ".shp", "Block_ID =" & BlockID


Output_Feature_Class = "C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\VectorB" & BlockID & "_" & popNo & ".shp"
Thiessens = "ThiessenNew" & BlockID & "_" & popNo
LandBlock = "LandBlock" & BlockID

' Process: Clip...
GP.Clip_analysis Thiessens, LandBlock, Output_Feature_Class, ""


Call UpDateVector3BG(BlockID, strPopNo)

Call UpdateVector3BValue(BlockID, strPopNo)


Call DeleteFCclass2("ThiessenNew", BlockID, strPopNo)

Call DeleteFCclass("LandBlock", BlockID)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried this?<br/> inputshp = "C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\CentroidsB" & BlockID & ".shp"<br/>
outputshp = "C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\ThiessenNew" & BlockID & "_" & popNo & ".shp"<br/>
GP.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis inputshp, outputshp, "ONLY_FID"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it does not appear you defined an output path for your OutputThiessens variable.

```
OutputThiessens = "C:\LACONISS\LandSpaCES\Thiessen" & BlockID & "_" & popNo & ".shp"
```

Comment: I tried that, but this is not the problem.